# What's the best way to add a form in a node template?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, forms

I already have a node created with some custom fields, I would like to show a specific form in the detail page of the node that i created (using the ***node.tpl.php*** file)

Why? because I need to use some values of the node to custom parts of that form

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: There are a number of different ways - what are your criteria for "clean"/"best"/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to create a variable for your template in hook_preprocess_node():

```
function hook_preprocess_node(&$vars)
{
  $form = drupal_get_form('form_name');
  $vars['my_form'] = render($form);
}
```

Now you can drop the form anywhere in your template as the variable `$my_form`